# copying value of one struct to another

Tags: c++, struct

I want to copy the values of one struct to another which has the same template.
Below is the sample code, where `struct list` is the template structure. Calling `func1()` must copy the contents of `li` to `ref`.
But when copy is performed segmentation fault occurs. Where I am going wrong with it ?

**foo.cpp**

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
class bar
{
    public:
        void func1(const list& li);
};

void bar::func1(const list& li)
{
    listref ref = nullptr;
    ref = (listref)malloc(sizeof(listref));
    ref->a = li.a;//segfault occurs here
    ref->b = li.b;
    ref->c = li.c;
    ref->d = li.d;
}
```

**foo.h**

```
#include<iostream>
    struct list
    {
        std::string a;
        int b;
        int c;
        const char* d;
    };
    typedef struct list* listref;
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "foo.h"
#include "foo.cpp"
int main()
{
    list l1;
    std::string temp = "alpha";

    l1.a = "alphabet";
    l1.b = 60;
    l1.c = 43;
    l1.d = temp.c_str();

    bar b;
    b.func1(l1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see no templates here. Are you sure you mean "template"?

Comment: `typedef struct list* listref;` Don't do this or mistakes like this happen: `(listref)malloc(sizeof(listref));`. You want to allocate a `list`, not a pointer to list.

Comment: I see several mistakes. However, I suggest you keeping consistency with `C++` style. Your code is too much mix of `C` with a lot of potential *undefined behaviour*...

Comment: My advice is to put away the `C` language books and materials you're using, and use `C++` properly.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing C and C++ concepts and this is what happens!

Your class `list` contains a member of the C++ type `std::string`, a complex class with semantics that you need to uphold.

Then you do a `malloc` over it!

Even if your size argument to `malloc` were correct (which it isn't; you merely gave it the size of a pointer), this does not properly construct anything. It should be `new` or `std::make_unique`!

Do not mix C and C++ idioms.